# RAID 1+0 with odd number of drives

Tags: raid, dell, raid10

Recently I set up a Dell R720 to be a file server. 2 of the 16 drives were used for the OS (RAID 1) while the other 14 were used for RAID 10, or so I thought. I opened up OpenManage today and saw that there are 6 spans of drives but in one of those spans, there is only 1 drive. Looking deeper, I see that there is one drive not part of the RAID that is just in a "ready" state.

I swear that I didn't set it up like this but here we are. Is it possible to add this one drive to the RAID or am I going to need to blow away the whole thing and start over.

Side question, is it even possible to have a RAID 10 with an odd number of drives?[image]
[image]

Comment: Seems likely that 'spare' failed or fell out of the volume or something.  Are you sure it is in a healthy state?

Comment: I don't know why you got downvotes - it's perfectly possible to have a R1/10 with an odd-number of disks, either on purpose or by mistake. In fact HPE's newer disk controller very specifically allow for a three-disk R1 where there's essentially three copies of the data - not sure I know WHY they offer this but they do.

Comment: @chopper3 Because three copies of a RAID dataset allows for more advanced self-healing features. I'm not certain if they're implementing them, but they better be with that amount of data copies.

Comment: I saw something similar a short while ago. It was an issue with IDRAC in my case, though..

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I booted into the RAID BIOS and saw that the drive in question (drive 12) was showing as foreign. After re-seating the drive it started rebuild in the correct span. Not sure what happened but its fixed